# Convert SQL Server 2012 SSIS package to 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssis

I've created a few SSIS packages in SQL Server 2012 that I need to run on SQL Server 2008. I've been told that it is impossible in their current state.

Is there a way to convert the 2012 packages to a 2008 version?

If not, what are my alternatives? Start over?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes,  you'll need to recreate the package in 2008. 2005/2008 packages can be upgraded to 2012, but downgrading doesn't work.

There is a [codeplex project/utility](http://ssisdowngrade.codeplex.com/) that can move 2008 packages to 2005 by changing version numbers, and making small changes to the XML. Unfortunately this approach doesn't work with 2012, as the package format went through some big changes.

Comment: Hi Matt! Welcome to our site, we're really glad you're here. If you don't feel shy, you can pass and say hello on [The Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap), too.